# What is a modern equivalent for smokeping?

Tags: linux

I am looking for simple software that allows me to monitor popular webhosters in the following months to see performance.

I have used smokeping in the past for this purpose, but it seems that smokeping is horribly outdated and pretty hard to configure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/

I don't see anything "horribly outdated" and "pretty hard to configure." about smokeping compared to other packages.  In fact if you only want to measure latency (so you don't need a full network monitoring system like [Opennms](http://opennms.org) or [Nagios](http://nagios.org)) I always recommend smokeping.

Comment: [linuxserver/smokeping](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/smokeping) makes configuring a bit easier. Mount the config-dir, fire up, edit the configuration, restart.